# Timeout not working in PHP Httpful request

Tags: php, httpful

I am having an http request and I am using "Httpful Request" to send it in PHP.
I am setting a timeout of 20 seconds also in the request as follows:

```
$req = Request::get($Url);
$response = $req->timeoutIn(20)->expectsHtml()->send();
```

I was expecting to get an exception after timeout happens and I can handle the exception. But I am getting the following php Fatal error. Why is it so?

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   phar://C:/CapPortal/cpPortal/source/wordpress/httpful.phar/Httpful/Request.php
>   on line 202

Comment: Could be that you're doing something that's 11 seconds long and then waiting for another 19 seconds before PHP gives up. If you set a `timeoutIn(1)` would that work?

Comment: What you pointed out is correct. As @robske_110 told, set_time_limit(30) just before my request solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [set_time_limit($seconds)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php) to set that limit higher, if you need more execution time. You can also set it to 0, which means infinite. Warning: Apache (if you're using php with it) may also limit php's execution time.

Comment: I don't want to change the php time limit. I am giving a timeout in my request to catch the exception before php max execution time reaches.

Comment: I added set_time_limit(30) just before my request solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `httpful` module, itself has some method to set time out name is `timeoutIn()`.
So you can add this method to your code and set the time out, for example to 50 seconds:

`$response = $req->timeoutIn(20)->expectsHtml()->timeoutIn(50)->send();`

It work fine for me.